# AWK if field one is equal to vaiable value then update field two and three

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk, sh

I am working on a shell script to process a CSV file. I have a csv file as shown below.

```
cat list.csv
0003812,3,2
0000808,0,0
0003346,1,0
0018003,8,1
0044477,3,0
0197183,0,0
```

In the script i come upto logic where i get value of first field from this file in a varible "var". I need to increment field two and three if the value of vaiable "var" matches field 1. I need to make sure that the changed values are put back in the same field in the same file.

I tried something like below but it doesnot work

```
awk -F, '$1=="$var" {$2+=1;$3+=1}1' OFS=, /foo/bar.csv
```

Below is expected output if var="0044477"

```
Output
0003812,3,2
0000808,0,0
0003346,1,0
0018003,8,1
0044477,4,1
0197183,0,0
```

Comment: I aslo need to reset the field three values to zero if field two valued are non-zero.

Output at the end.
0003812,3,0
0000808,0,0
0003346,1,0
0018003,8,0
0044477,4,0
0197183,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` like this:

```
var='0044477'

awk -v val="$var" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1==val{$2++; $3++} 1' list.csv

0003812,3,2
0000808,0,0
0003346,1,0
0018003,8,1
0044477,4,1
0197183,0,0
```

Comment: At the end of the script i want to reset field three values to zero if field two values are non-zero. Can you tell me how to compare value with field value or how i can achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what output do you need. Can you show expected output in your question again?

Answer (score -1):

Please use below command.

Var='some_value'

```
awk -F',' '{ if($1=='"$Var"') { print $1,$2+1,$3+1 } else {print $1,$2,$3} }' file.dat
```

Comment: Never let shell variables expand their value to become part of an awk script or you open yourself up to many insidious problems. Use `-v` to set an awk variable instead.